# Dell Vostro 5515 with Ubuntu 20.04 dies after suspend

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, dell-vostro

I have got two the same Dell Vostro 5515 (AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics 1.80 GHz). On both I install official Ubuntu 20.04 LTS distro on new created partition next to build in Windows 10.

Both have the same symptoms: both dies totally after suspend - Only hard reset can turn back my laptops to life (plug out everything, screw up the bottom chassis, plug out the battery and hold on for 30 seconds power button). And I am totally aware saying "dies", there is any, totally any contact with them.

Its some kind of nightmare. I have install in the same way Ubuntu on X different types of machines (including Dell ones), and it always works perfectly. I was, and I am now, totally aware of every step I take during the Ubuntu installation and I am not able to point out, what is wrong. It must be said that on Windows I do not have this issue.

Furthermore - I perform experiment, on both I perform two kinds of installation - minimal, and full (including third party software). Result: Ubuntu Suspend kills my laptops in the same way.

Can I please any clues and help on that - did anyone have similar issues?

All the best

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED. Update of kernel to version above 5.14 solves the problem! :) In my case I check version with `uname -r` and update kernel via `Ubuntu mainline kernel installer`. Important is to disable secure boot in BIOS. Next thing is that, it is safer to not take a try with highest kernel version, because of some dependencies problems. Thus I decide to install 5.15, whereas 5.16 was to high for me. Every step can be easily googled. More detailed hints can be found here: https://dev.to/epassaro/fix-suspend-issues-on-dell-7405-2-in-1-3l1b

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same thing that you observed, except with my Inspiron 5515.
Today I had my Inspiron 5515 on, but instead of powering it off like I usually would, I left it idle and after 20 mins it went into suspend automatically.
After that, no power (whether power adapter was connected/disconnected - even if holding power off for 10 seconds then power back on -> still no power)

I'm dual booting with Ubuntu + Windows - using Ubuntu mainly -> same as you, once I unplug/replug the battery after opening up the machine it works around the issue.
My Inspiron 5515 is still under warranty, but so far Dell has been replacing motherboards when I call for support (they didn't believe me when I said it's probably not a motherboard issue, lol! Now it's the 3rd one so I figured I'd investigate myself).

My thoughts here are:

1. Ubuntu plays a part in this equation, here's a bug ticket from Ubuntu that's interesting:
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1909005
2. The 5515 model (in my case Inspiron) seems to be involved too -> even if we could be hitting a bug in Ubuntu, I'd still figure that the machine should be able to power up again, especially since like you've mentioned it seems to be specific to certain hardware models -> in the past I've been able to workaround this issue on my Inspiron 5515 by holding the power button as a hard reset, but today I had to use your workaround of disconnect/reconnect the battery for the workaround to take effect. Maybe certain models don't have a good way to properly hard reset without disassembling the machine, that's my best guess without being a hardware engineer ;)

My thoughts: Dell probably won't be interested in understanding/resolving this, best to disable/avoid suspending on your machine, and if you suspect this issue matches the bug ticket above you can post that you've matched the issue.

Good luck!